# Perl one liner regex throwing bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I have a PERL one liner I am trying to use against a config file that contains a comma separated list of email addresses.

```
perl -nle 'print for m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$/i)/g'
```

returns bash:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

It seems the regex is not playing well with the shell.  I suspect something is not being properly escaped but due the nature of the error the regex itself I have no idea where to look.  Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose the colored syntax highlighting here answers your question pretty well :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't even notice that until you pointed it out. :)

Answer (score 8):

That's because you've got a single quote which you hoped was inside your regex, but the shell doesn't know that.   This time, you can get away with double quotes around the Perl expression:

```
perl -nle "print for m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$/i)/g"
```

More generally, you need to use the `'\''` trick:

```
perl -nle 'print for m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.'\'']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$/i)/g'
```

The `'\''` embeds a single quote in a single-quoted string in shell; the first quote closes the current single quoted string; the backslash quote embeds a single quote; and the last quote starts a new single-quoted string.

Comment: hmm... now I am getting: Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*) <-- HERE *$/ at -e line 1.

Comment: @oljones: That's because you genuinely have more `)`s than `(`s in your pattern. I'm not sure if they extra ones are the result of too much copy-and-paste, or if they're supposed to be `\)`, or what.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in your first logical group; the `'` is closing your string to be evaluated before you want it to be.

```
perl -nle 'print for m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.' <-- that character
```

try using `"`

```
perl -nle "print for m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$/i)/g"
```

Comment: Same error as above... `Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\* Members= (\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*) <-- HERE *$/ at -e line 1.`

Comment: There's no way to escape a single quote inside a single quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, use `"` instead of `'`.

And there is another error at the end of your regex:

```
([,])*)*$/i)/g
```

must be written:

```
(,)*$/ig
```

I'm not sure your regex do what you want, please show some lines of the file in order to give you a better answer.